# Unable to modify folder permissions though I am administrator

Tags: windows-8.1, file-permissions

I have [viewed](https://superuser.com/questions/33373/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-save-in-a-folder-that-windows-7-denies-me-from) this already but my problem still remains unsolved

I am unable to save files on any folders in Programfile(x86) as i keep getting the following error message

[image]

It appears the issues lies with the fact that I do not have full control of Programfile(x86) but I am unable to modify the access control even though I am the administrator

[image]

Proof I am administrator

[image]

I dont understand why this is happening , can someone explain to me how to solve this problem ??

Comment: Are you specifcally running Notepad++ "as Administrator" (as suggested in the answer to the question you linked)?  Just using an Administrator account isn't enough.

Comment: So in reality, the problem is that your Run As Administrator is missing, not that you can't save to the folder (that's answered in the link you provided). Please edit your question to be about that, instead of just being a duplicate of the other (or just request it be closed by flagging a mod, and start a new one).  While re-doing your question, please explain what you see when you right click the Notepad++ icon, a screenshot would be good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get permissions to save in a folder that Windows 7 denies me from?](http://superuser.com/questions/33373/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-save-in-a-folder-that-windows-7-denies-me-from)